# Ruboto: Android SDK Tools is missing

Tags: android, ruboto

I'm trying to develop android apps using Ruboto. I can't seem to get it all up and running though. When I try to run something like:

```
ruboto gen app --package com.test.me --name Test --target android-17
```

I got the following output:

```
Found '/usr/bin/adb' but it is not in a proper Android SDK installation.
RuntimeError: The '<ANDROID_HOME>/tools' directory is missing.
Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to a proper Android SDK installation.
```

I have followed the guide on the Ruboto git site (https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Environment-setup-for-ubuntu) but whatever I do, I still get that error. When I manually go to the directory, the tools directory isn't missing.

Some extra info:

- I am using Ubuntu 13.10.
- I installed every SDK after running `android` in the terminal.
- I am using jruby through rvm

Comment: have you added the ANDROID_HOME variable?

Comment: Yes I did, I can cd to $ANDROID_HOME. When I do I go to that directory but whenever I want to create a new app it says there isn't a ANDROID_HOME directory.

Comment: what is the path. paste the path